# TSQL, Ordering of ORDER BY

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given a table of

```
Name   Age
Bob    30
Paul   35
John   35
```

and a statement

```
select * from table ORDER BY Age DESC
```

What is the ordering of the resulting table?

```
Name   Age
Paul   35
John   35
Bob    30
```

or

```
Name   Age
John   35
Paul   35
Bob    30
```

or undefined behaviour?

Comment: As it was explained to me, never rely on the order of rows coming back when you haven't specified.

Comment: If you need an order - be specific about it. If it's not specified, it's not guaranteed / defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's guaranteed that `Bob` will be the last row of the resultset. The relative ordering of the other rows isn't guaranteed in any way.

If you need guaranteed ordering then you need to be explicit about it. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY age DESC,
         name ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY Age DESC, Name [ASC|DESC]`

If you omit the `ORDER BY` clause, the optimizer will decide the order for you. In my experience, it is **usually** however the data is ordered on the disk. If there is a clustered index (usually the primary key), it will be its order. **However**, as @Martin pointed out, this is not guaranteed. If you want a specific order, specify it.

Comment: This is not defined or guaranteed.

Comment: @Martin, you are correct. I have modified my answer to reflect your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table 
ORDER BY Age DESC , name asc
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - if you do not specify the "name" as an ORDER BY criteria - is the order somehow defined - or not??

Answer (score 0):

The result finally is not in any defined or garuanteed order in which you can expect results.